# Problem in running python program with Colab for training dataset with config file

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, dataset, google-colaboratory, app-config

I want to run a python program `train.py` with colab so I use following line code.

```
 !python /content/nameprogram/train.py --config /content/nameprogram/configs/config.yml
```

In config file, address of datasets and other parameters are placed and I show you part of line codes for address of dataset for train and test and other parameters in `config.yml`

```
#data
data_obj: "/content/nameprogram/data/data_{}_obj.lmdb"
data_q: "/content/nameprogram/data/data_{}_q.lmdb"

max_seq_length: 20
max_obj_num: 4
max_q_num: 25
batch_size: 24
```

Dataset and config file and the .py file are located in these paths and when I run above line code, config file is detected and could be seen all the parameters in that config file.

My problem is that when I run above line code, dataset didn't load for program with this address in config file and couldn't recognize dataset However, the config file is loaded correctly and loaded other parameters in that file.
it gives me following error and can't load dataset for this program for training.

```
self.env = lmdb.open( lmdb.Error: /content/nameprogram/data/data_trainval_obj.lmdb: No such file or directory
```

How could I solve my problem?
Is it possible that I should have initial addresses differently? (If yes how to change?)

Comment: is your filename data_trainval_obj.lmdb and does it exist in data directory? can you please check it with os.path.isfile("/content/nameprogram/data/data_trainval_obj.lmdb")

Comment: Hi @HKay, when I run your that line code, response was "true" so is it good or bad and if it's bad what can I do to solve this problem.

Comment: @HKay I check it line code for data_trainval_q.lmdb too and it was true too

Comment: @HKay when I run os.removedirs("/content/nameprogram/data/data_trainval_obj.lmdb") it gives me NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/content/nameprogram/data/data_trainval_obj.lmdb'

Comment: if os.path.isfile gave true, it is a good thing, it means you have a file right there but somehow lmdb.open is unable to read it. Would you mind using the path directly i.e. copy pasting inside lmdb.open("/content/nameprogram/data/data_trainval_obj.lmdb") rather than reading it from config.yml. You should read it form there successfully as os.path.isfile detects it there. After you can read it successfully by manually putting the path there, you can just remove both " from your path in config.yml and read it again, it will run fine.

Comment: @HKay Thank you for your guide but it seems doesn't work for me. I change code         self.env = lmdb.open("/content/nameprogram/data/data_trainval_obj.lmdb",
            max_readers=1,readonly=True,lock=False,readahead=False,meminit=False) and it gives me this error     self.env = lmdb.open(
lmdb.Error: /content/nameprogram/data/data_trainval_obj.lmdb: Not a directory         .I change without "" but doesn't work to me.

Comment: @HKay In addition without these changes, I removed "" in command dataset address, in config.yml but it doesn't work too.

Comment: @HKay ,I send part of code because may be I am in wrong.                                  
class head(object):
    def __init__(self, features_path: str, in_memory: bool = False):
        self.features_path = features_path
        self._in_memory = in_memory
        
        self.env = 
lmdb.open(self.features_path,max_readers=1,readonly=True,lock=False,readahead=False,meminit=False,)

Comment: @HKay I changed with your guide ad following                                                          class head(object):

    def __init__(self, features_path: str, in_memory: bool = False):
        self.features_path = features_path
        self._in_memory = in_memory
        
        self.env = 
lmdb.open("/content/nameprogram/data/data_trainval_obj.lmdb",max_readers=1,readonly=True,lock=False,readahead=False,meminit=False,)

Comment: I don't know much about lmdb but I have looked at lmdb.open documentation, it looks like it expects the directory as an input because of subdir default value is true, can you run this instead self.env = lmdb.open("/content/nameprogram/data/data_trainval_obj.lmdb",max_readers=1,readonly=True,lock=False,readahead=False,meminit=False,subdir=False)

Comment: @HKay Thank you so much for fast reply. I will change with you guide but could I ask another question? doesn't need to change other variable or parameters in that head class?

Comment: head (should be written as Head according to pep8 standards) class belongs to your code so I don't know where you are using the class variable but as for now your lmdb.open function is giving an error, for that to fix, you need to either provide a directory or you can change the subdir variable to false.

Comment: I get it. Thank you so much for your great guide. I am changing code with your guides. I hope it work.

Comment: please let us know if it works with that change. In that case, I will add the changes as an answer to this question so that in the future, if someone else faces this issue, they can get the changes from the answer directly rather than going through all these comments.

Comment: @HKay Yes, be sure, if I get the answer, I will inform you with all the changes to know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of .mdb files in the subsets of LMDB file. when I downloaded .lmdb files from dropbox with following code

```
!wget -O /content/nameprogram/data/data_trainval_obj.lmdb https://www.dropbox.com/sh/data_trainval_obj.lmdb?dl=0
```

That file saved as `named.lmdb?dl=0` and when I renamed as `named.lmdb` and removed `?dl=0` I couldn't see that .mdb subfiles again. so, I downloaded that .mdb files one by one. And after I do that, `lmdb.open("path")` could recognize directory.